# Google login callback always shows "immediate_failed"

Tags: php, api, google-api, facebook-social-plugins, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google login to my website. 
I followed google developers code.
Reference: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button

But I always get response result as "immediate_failed" from signinCallback function.
Does anyone know the solution for this?

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
 if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {

// Update the app to reflect a signed in user
// Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');

} else {

// Update the app to reflect a signed out user
// Possible error values:
//   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
//   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
//   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);

}
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code that references this funciton?

Comment: Yes i have used the code from google developers.
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button

Comment: Also see here , **Choosing a sign-in flow** https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/?hl=en#using_the_client-side_flow

Comment: I followed same code as in 
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/?hl=en#using_the_client-side_flow
But still response is same “immediate_failed”

Comment: Thanks Guys. I got it working.:) 
I just needed to turn on Google+ Domain Api and 
fill up the consent screen properly. 
https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/